# How to get parent directory of sbt file

Tags: scala, path, compilation, sbt

I have the following line in my sbt file:

```
target in Compile in doc := baseDirectory.value / "docs"
```

This is creates a folder in the directory one level below the one I am aiming for. I would like to get essentially (pseudocode):

```
parentDirectory = parent of baseDirectory
target in Compile in doc := parentDirectory.value / "docs"
```

Where now "docs" sits next to the baseDirectory, as opposed to in it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: Project Structure

```
myFolder/project/build.sbt
```

If I run "docs" in sbt shell, I get the following output:

```
myFolder/project/docs/
```

What I want instead is:

```
myFolder/docs/
myFolder/project/build.sbt
```

The reason I want to do this is so I can host my docs on github pages in the same directory. This seems the easiest way without complicating stuff.

Comment: What is the base directory for you? It would be good if you can show the directory structure you had and the one you want and why.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I added some further comments

Comment: If you have `build.sbt` in project, that means that `project` is your repo. Having docs outside means it shouldn't be longer managed by SBT and it shouldn't be part of the repository. There are tons of opensource repositories that have their docs inside the repo on github pages without any problem, not sure why you need this.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, so unfortunately my repo is the myFolder (it contains some other stuff alongside the project due to some requirements). So what happens is if I push to git, I am pushing myFolder to Github, but due to the nested nature github cannot pick up the index.html file for the docs. I would prefer to have my code seperate but unfortunately I cannot do so for this particular repo

Comment: Another common approach is to have a different branch for your github pages and in your CI/CD workflow you generate the docs and push them to the other branch which only has the site info.

Comment: thanks I will give this a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baseDirectory.value` is of type `java.io.File`, so you can use all these methods:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

The relevant one here would be `getParentFile`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider standard two successive dots `..` notation to represent parent directory, for example

```
Compile / doc / target := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "docs"
```

Alternatively `file("..")` could also work

```
Compile / doc / target := file("../docs")
```

You might want to create a dedicated setting for reuse

```
lazy val parentOfBaseDirectory = settingKey[File]("Parent of base directory")
parentOfBaseDirectory := baseDirectory.value / ".."
```

---

Couple of side notes:

You can make quick one off experiments within sbt shell using `set` and semicolon `;`

```
set Compile/doc/target := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "docs"; doc
```

The reason `/` syntax works is because `File` is implicitly converted to sbt's [`RichFile`](https://github.com/sbt/io/blob/4b8c60e1aef405e12217fc9fc60a759d5b3bce56/io/src/main/scala/sbt/io/Path.scala#L32) which provides additional useful extension methods.